# Resize mayavi window

Tags: python, window, vtk, mayavi

I guess the solution is quite easy. However I can't find any example on how to change the window size of the mayavi renderer.

sample code:

```
import numpy as np
from tvtk.api import tvtk
from mayavi import mlab

points = np.random.normal(0, 1, (1000, 3))
ug = tvtk.UnstructuredGrid(points=points)
ug.point_data.scalars = np.sqrt(np.sum(points**2, axis=1))
ug.point_data.scalars.name = "value"
ds = mlab.pipeline.add_dataset(ug)
delaunay = mlab.pipeline.delaunay3d(ds)
iso = mlab.pipeline.iso_surface(delaunay)
iso.actor.property.opacity = 0.1
iso.contour.number_of_contours = 10
mlab.show()
```

I've tried the following:

```
scene=mlab.gcf().scene
scene.set_size((600,600))
```

nothing changes.

best regards and thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

```
fig = mlab.figure(size=(600,600))
#then the rest of your code
```

Comment: The question asks how to change the size of existing renderer. For that purpose, this method does not work, at least in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Since Mayavi render plots using x3dom its possible by modifying DOM tree with javascript. I wrote this js-cell in my jupyter notebook but i believe it will work inside custom.js file jupyter provides.
To be honest not sure about performance because js itself is pretty new for me.

```
%%javascript

MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver;
var width = 600;
var height = 600;

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations, observer) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation){
        if (mutation.target.className === 'x3dom-canvas')
        {
            var target = mutation.target;
            if (target.getAttribute('width') < width)
                target.setAttribute('width', width);

            if (target.getAttribute('height') < height)
                target.setAttribute('height', height);
        }
    });
});

observer.observe(document.body, {
    subtree: true,
    attributes: true
});
```

Code is observing DOM tree modifications (attributes to be clear) and changing specific node's attributes which created by Mayavi.